# how to move a wordpress blog to my static site

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am sorry in advance for the noob question. I am just looking for direction. I have read the codex and scoured this site for help and cannot find anything useful.

Here's the situation. My client has an old wordpress site. I am building her a new HTML5 site but want to carry her old blog posts and comment structure over.

So right now I have www.testsite.com which is her wordpress site and the only part I want to take is /blog. I have my new site under testsite.com/new and the new wp installation under testsite.com/new/blog

If this makes sense to anyone can you think of the best way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This question belongs on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [Scoured, you say?](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wordpress+migrate)

Answer (score 0):

Is your client concern about her blog template or is it just plain template from WordPress? Otherwise you can backup everything from her old WordPress and put it on the new blog. Or You have to pull everything whats on her old WordPress database and retrieve it back to her new website.

Answer (score 0):

the best suggestion for you to create wordpress theme for old site or convert the HTML5 template to wordpress because wordpress navigates to the url `testsite.com/new`, it will bother you. And much more wordpress conflicts with your HTL5 template in style.

Another thing you can do as new installation of wordpress in blog directory under new folder over the old database. As a result you can navigate the wordpress as `testsite.com/new/blog`. And you can customize wordpress site to show only the blog posts.